# Sitefinity - Custom backend login widget not working in Sitefinity 12.2 after upgrade

Tags: content-management-system, upgrade, sitefinity

We have custom login widget which we have been using in Sitefinity 8 which has OTP authentication. After upgrade to Sitefinity 12.2, not able to render the custom login widget in back-end login page. Saw in few documents like sitefinity 12 doesn't support custom widget in back-end login page.

Is there any way to use the custom login widget for sitefinity back-end login. Please help with some suggestions or solutions, so that we can configure the custom widget.

Question modified :
After making the some configuration changes mentioned by Vesilev, now the login form is rendering in the UI. But while checking for the valid user and if yes it goes to redirect.And throws error :
"Server cannot set status after HTTP headers have been sent".
Please find the code below :

```
 UserLoggingReason reason = SecurityManager.AuthenticateUser("Default", this.username.Text, true, out user);
                        if (reason == UserLoggingReason.Success)
                        {
                            Response.Redirect("~/Sitefinity/Dashboard");
                        }
                        else if (reason == UserLoggingReason.Unknown)
                        {
                            this.message.Text = "Incorrect Username/Password Combination";
                        }
```

Not able to login into the system as this is throwing error from Response.Redirect.Need some suggestions/help to resolve this.

Comment: Is your AuthenticationMode set to Claims or Forms (in administration/settings/advanced/security). Also, is your AuthenticationProtocol set to OpenId or SWT (in administration/settings/advanced/authentication) ? Try setting the latter to SWT and see if this helps

Comment: Tried the same setting mentioned above and yes the login page came and tried debugging button click events of the custom widget is getting triggered but after validation of user id and password it is going to Application_Error in Global.asax with error message Server cannot set status after HTTP headers have been sent.

Comment: i tried adding  HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); to ApplicationBeginRequest but did not help.

Comment: so now the custom login form renders, but there is an issue with the code? if so, I suggest you update your OP and include your code

Comment: Hi @Veselin, can you help to revert the following change: 
AuthenticationProtocol set to OpenId or SWT. I am not able to login into the system, is there a way to revert this. i changed to openid in config for authentication but still not working

Comment: The change is saved either in the file system (app_Data/sitefinity/configuration/ authentication.config) or in the database (table sf_xml_config_items). revert your change there and restart the site.

Comment: Thank you .. i was able to revert from the config.